# How to stop reading from socket

Tags: c, sockets

I'm so lost.  I can't figure out how to stop reading from the server.  I'm basically sending a list of every file in the directory from the server to the client.  Heres what I'm doing.

SERVER SIDE:

```
 struct dirent *ep = readdir(dp);      
    while( ep ){  
        sprintf(buf, "%s", (ep->d_name));
        n = write(newsock, buf, MAX );           
        ep = readdir(dp);  
    }
```

CLIENT SIDE:

```
while( n = read(sock, buf, MAX)){
    printf("buf: %s\n" , buf);       
}
```

So the server side stuff works fine.  I can see I'm sending all the file names right, but on the client side it reads all the names but just sits waiting to read more.

Comment: Why are you sending all the NUL bytes (and garbage)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You either need to send some "EOF" indicator from the server so the client knows to break the loop, or have the server close the socket (after allowing 'some time' for the client to read all the data).  This will cause the read to exit with an error condition.

Second is easier on the face of it, first is likely to be more reliable and efficient.  Congratulations, you have now built your first communications protocol.

Comment: So if at the end of my server side stuff if I just write like n = write(newsock, "-1", MAX ); and on the client side just do the while loop like while( strcmp( buf, "-1" ) != 0 ) ... is that acceptable?  Seems like it works except when I run other commands the server starts to just send back more file names when it should be sending something completely different.

Comment: A reasonable approach might be to have the client close the socket after the end of file list signal "-1" is read, and then have the server and client establish a new socket for the next data exchange.  My guess is you have some logic error in the revised code that causes the behaviour you describe here.  Also as noted you don't want to write MAX every time, just send the actual data with a separator character (refining the protocol).  You are wasting space on the wire otherwise.

Comment: that can happen... best of luck. This protocol idea is very powerful and widely-used, after all your sockets don't know about the data you are sending so the client and server must have a shared understanding of what to expect.

Answer (score 1):

Define a protocol.

A very simple one might be to let the server send an empty (0-length) file name to the client to tell the client that it's done with sending. To successfully do so you might like to delimit each file name by for example an addtionaly `\r\n` sequence, or similar.